# How to install Braintree Java server SDK with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints, braintree

In the Braintree docs they specify how to install the Braintree Java SDK with Maven and how to install it manually. I would like to know if I can install Braintree using Gradle in the backend module of my Android app. I am trying to use my endpoints class as the backend for the Braintree payments.

So how do I install Braintree Java server SDK using gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following Maven dependency definition:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.braintreepayments.gateway</groupId>
  <artifactId>braintree-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.65.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The Gradle equivalent would be the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:2.65.0'
}
```